# Why does (( (λf.λx.f(f(f(x)))) (λg.λy.g(g(y))) ) (λz.z + 1)) (0) evaluate to 8?

Tags: python, lambda, lambda-calculus

So I have this lambda expression: `(λf.λx.f(f(f(x)))) (λg.λy.g(g(y)))(λz.z + 1)(0)` and I'm trying to evaluate it by hand. They way I'm thinking about this is that `(λf.λx.f(f(f(x))))` basically represents the expression `f(f(f(x)))`. Then likewise `(λg.λy.g(g(y)))` represents the expression `g(g(y))`. Then `g(g(y))` is passed in to replace f. So we get `g(g(g(g(g(g(y))))))`. Or `g` composed with itself `6` times. Then we pass in `z+1` for `g` and then plug in `0` into that final expression and we wind up with `6`.

```
>>>(((lambda f: lambda x: f(f(f(x))))(lambda g: lambda y: g(g(y))))(lambda z: z+1))(0)
8
```

The problem is that when I go to verify this answer using python's built in lambda calculus tools I get 8 as the answer.

So clearly I'm doing my evaluation wrong. I'm thinking of 2 g compositions being multiplied by 3 f compositions to get 6. But clearly I'm supposed to be thinking of it as 2^3 compositions but I don't understand why.

Comment: Excellent job translating that lambda expression to Python, by the way. There are several subtleties to the lambda calculus, and you seem to understand the semantics well to be able to convert it seamlessly into a concrete programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is failing you somewhat. It's tempting to try to compose those two expressions the "intuitive" way, but doing so oversimplifies the problem. Let's take a look at the first couple of steps.

Here's your lambda expression with some of the extraneous parentheses removed for readability purposes

```
(λf.λx.f(f(fx))) (λg.λy.g(gy)) (λz.z+1) 0
```

Now, your intuition tells you that we "compose" the first two functions by letting `f` be `λy.g(gy)`. But that's not really the case. See, we're not letting `f` be `λy.g(gy)`; we're letting `f` be `λg.λy.g(gy)` (the `g` is still an argument at this time). So the first simplification applies as

```
(λx.(λg.λy.g(gy))((λg.λy.g(gy))((λg.λy.g(gy))x))) (λz.z+1) 0
```

It's a confusing mess, but the point is the bit that's being repeated still has a `g` argument. Then we plug in `λz.z+1` for `x`, which is admittedly fairly simple

```
(λg.λy.g(gy)) ((λg.λy.g(gy))((λg.λy.g(gy))(λz.z+1))) 0
```

Alright. Now in the innermost redex we're going to let `g` be `(λz.z+1)`. So, glossing over a few steps of the process, we're going to get a function on `y` which says "add one to this thing twice". i.e.

```
(λg.λy.g(gy)) ((λg.λy.g(gy))(λy.y+2)) 0
```

Okay, now let's do it again. The left-hand side of the redex is the same as before, so we're going to do the thing on the right-hand side twice. The thing on the right-hand side is "add one to this number", so we get

```
(λg.λy.g(gy)) (λy.y+4) 0
```

Finally, do it one last time. We're adding four to a number twice.

```
(λy.y+8) 0
```

And for the grand prize, zero plus eight is...

```
8
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a good exercise to walk it through step by step like Silvio, but more simply:

You apply f->f^3 to g->g^2, isn't that g->(((g^2)^2)^2) = g^8?
and so (+1)^8 (0) = 8

Comment: I see so my intuition was almost right, but it was slightly wrong.
Can you help me try and explain this through a classical f(x) formalism? Like without the lambda notation I'm just trying to understand the order of operations here and it might help if I can understand it with normal function notation.

Like lets says f1(f,x)=(λf.λx.f(f(f(x)))) then f1(f,x)=f(f(f(x)))
Say f2(g,y)=(λg.λy.g(g(y))) then f2(g,y)=g(g(y))
Say f3(z)=z+1
Then let h1(g,x,y)=f1(f2(g,y),x)=g(g(y))(g(g(y))(g(g(y))))

But I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: It doesn't work this way, your notation f1(f,x)=(λf.λx.f(f(f(x)))) is wrong to start with. It's f1(f)=(λf.λx.f(f(f(x)))) or f1(f)(x)=f(f(f(x))), and similarly f2(g)=(λg.λy.g(g(y))) or f2(g)(y)=g(g(y)). f2 is here a 'second order' operator (transforming a function), not a a function of 2 variables) and f1 is a 'third order' operator (transforming a first order operator acting on a function). If you really want to bring the 0th order variable 'x' then I'm afraid you'll have to go carefully through all the steps like Silvio...

Comment: Maybe this will make it clearer? You can rewrite your python expression with a lambda of 2 variables for the outer operator: `(lambda f, x: f(f(f(x))))(lambda g: lambda y: g(g(y)), lambda z: z+1)(0)`  but I don't see how you can do that for the inner one...